# Simple descriptive statistics with inter-quartile mean. What about standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, descriptive-statistics

If one summarizes a data set with an inter-quartile (iqm) mean, rather than the mean calculated using the complete data set, is a standard deviation (sd) calculated using the complete data set then inconsistent with presenting the iqm?

Put another way, for consistency, should the sd be computed using the exact same data ( inter-quartile or complete ) that was used to compute the mean?

Comment: The inter-quartile mean in a box plot is the midpoint of the inter-quartile interval.  It does take all the data into account.  The standard deviation is a commonly used description of variability but there are probability distributions for which it does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelChernick  I am using IQM as defined by the mean of the data excluding the upper and lower quartiles http://www.statisticshowto.com/interquartile-mean-iqm-midmean/
It is supposed to be more robust against outliers.

Comment: @scitamehtam For what it's worth, I agree with your definition -- and so does [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean) -- though in my (perhaps limited) experience it's more often called the *midmean*. What Michael is talking about is usually called the [midhinge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midhinge).

Comment: I've never seen the SD of the data between the quartiles being used as a measure. I can't see any reason to calculate it.

Comment: If you like mid-means, you might perhaps consider a quartile-winsorized standard deviation -- rather than eliminate data outside the quartiles, move it to the quartiles and then calculate a form of standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [interquartile mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean) (or midmean), the maybe you should also report its standard error ?  But, if what you want is some robust measure of spread of the data, then choose such a measure (maybe MAD?), preferably a known one. Your proposal of using the standard deviation of the data between the first and third quartile doesn't seem to have much meaning.